# How to prove that the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} (1+2x)^x$ is $1$?

Tags: calculus

I know that the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} (1+2x)^x = 1$. But how do I explain to students the first year of calculus?
Thanks!

Comment: Just how do you explain it to yourself?

Comment: $f(u,v)=u^v$ is continuous at $(u,v)=(1,1)$.

Comment: @Thomas: You mean $(u,v)=(1,0),$ yes?

Comment: The logarithm is $x\log(1+2x)$. It behaviour near $0$ needs little explanation. One can work with the exponential directly, but it may seem less obvious.

Comment: Yes, brain death.  @AndréNicolas

Comment: I believe there is a simpler approach: $\lim \limits_{x\to 0} (1+2x)^x=[(1+2x)^x\textbf{]}_{x=0}=1$

Comment: @GitGud That's essentially what Thomas Andrews wanted to hint at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $\delta=\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2})$, then
$$|(1+2\delta)^\delta-1|=(1+2\delta)^\delta-1 \leq (1+2\delta)-1 = 2\delta \leq \epsilon,$$
where the first equality holds since $\delta>0$ and the first inequality holds since $\delta<1$.

Answer (score 14):

Simply by continuity
$$\lim_{x\to0}(1+2x)^x=(1+2\times0)^0=1$$

Comment: Or just use that $x$, $\log(1+2x)$ and $e^x$ are all continuous at $x=0$. You don't need an estimate for $\log (1+2x)$.

Comment: if i could i would give additional +1. @Sami ben Romdhane

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You're wright, at first glance I  thought that there's an indeterminate form. Thanks.